# How do I build Qt with WebKit/WebEngine?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, webkit

I've been trying to build this for three days now and I keep getting everything except the web stuff I need.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to build Qt 5.5.1.

I have the following things (in the path of course):

- Perl 5.24
- Python 2.7.12
- Ruby 2.3.1
- Bison 3.0
- Flex 2.5.37
- Gperf 3.0.1
- Some version of ICU

I set up some environment stuff:

```
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64
SET _ROOT=C:\QtSource
SET PATH=%_ROOT%\qtbase\bin;%_ROOT%\gnuwin32\bin;%PATH%
SET QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2012
SET _ROOT=
SET INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\ICU\include
SET LIB=%LIB%;C:\ICU\lib
```

In C:\Build I call this:

```
C:\QtSource\configure.bat -prefix C:/Qt-5.5.1/ -debug-and-release -icu -mp -opensource -platform win32-msvc2012 -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng -nomake examples -nomake tests -opengl desktop
jom
jom install
```

Everything finishes building and I get almost everything except the web stuff that I need.

Looking through the Qt build directory, I can find dlls/libs for WebKit but not WebEngine. That's fine, I can use just WebKit. But it doesn't get "installed" and copying over the dlls from the build and the headers from the source doesn't work. When I compile my project, it gives me errors to the effect of

```
Cannot open include file: '../../Source/WebKit/qt/WidgetApi/qwebview.h'
```

How I can get the WebKit to work? And in the future, how can I ensure that I'm building WebEngine correctly?

Comment: Did you figure it out?  I have the problem where WebKit builds, but sometimes WebEngine doesn't.
I've also noticed that sometimes I need an Admin Cmd prompt, and sometimes 'jom' fails where nmake doesn't....

Comment: Honestly, I just gave up and ended up switching to a visual studio version where pre-built binaries were provided. Sorry for the late reply and good luck.